# How to launch window for install flash using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, flash

am using `asp.net` with `Jquery, Javascript and` **`flash`.**

**Problem:** I want to launch a window for install flash at client end(if not flash is not installed).

I used below javascript code to detect if flash is installed or not.

```
function detectFlash() {
    var hasFlash = false;
    try {
        var fo = (navigator.mimeTypes && navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash']) ? navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'].enabledPlugin : 0;
        if (fo) {
            hasFlash = true;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        if (navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'] != undefined) {
            hasFlash = true;
        }
    }
    if (hasFlash) {
        alert("flash is installed");
    }
}
```

but using above code I got only true or false if installed or not. but if not installed then how can I launch window to install flash using Javascript/JQuery or asp.net

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a redirect:

```
function detectFlash() {
    var hasFlash = false;
    try {
        var fo = (navigator.mimeTypes && navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash']) ? navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'].enabledPlugin : 0;
        if (fo) {
            hasFlash = true;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        if (navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'] != undefined) {
            hasFlash = true;
        }
    }
    if (hasFlash) {
        alert("flash is installed");
    } else {
        location = "http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/";
    }
}
```

You can try to open it in a new tab (browsers may block such actions):

- [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4907843/1420197)

### Enabling Flash plugin via JavaScript

Seriously, this is impossible (leave a comment if I'm wrong). Only the user is supposed to be able to enable this. Since this is a browser setting, this is different from a browser to another:

- [Chrome](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enabling-flash-player-chrome.html)
- [Firefox](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enabling-flash-player-firefox.html)
- [Internet Explorer](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/885448)

Unless the browsers don't expose a JavaScript API to enable this feature, we have this limitation.

Comment: this is correct but I want to launch a window which will ask to install

Comment: @Prog You cannot do that cross-platform. The best way is to let the user choose what to install.

Comment: yes it is better to let user choose  it. Can you tell me how we can enable flash plugin for browser using javascript/Jquery?

Comment: @Prog This is impossible, too. Such actions should be done by user, not by client scripts. You can show a friendly message instead (*Please install/enable flash.*).

Comment: are you sure that using client script we can not enable/disable plugin for browser? please give me link or reference for that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63690/discussion-between-ionic-bizu-and-prog).

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the page to this URL once **hasFlash** is false.

http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/current/support/install_flash_player.exe